# xcodebuild does not install into applications folder

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an XCode project with two executable targets, which I use for my own work (that is, I don't sell or publish the applications, but they are still important to me), which depends on one external project. Until now, it has been unproblematic to build the Application(s) and install into the /Applications folder. What I did, was go into the command line and type:

```
sudo xcodebuild -scheme Trainer install
```

This would install the target Trainer into the Applications folder, and the application could be run from there. If I tried to specify the target using `-target Trainer` instead, it would not work, as it would not find dependencies in the external project. Anyway, since last time it worked, two things have happened:

- I have upgraded to OS X 10.11
- I have upgraded XCode to Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)

Whatever the reason, xcodebuild does no longer install the built product into the /Applications folder. The last lines from the build log, when building with xcodebuild now are:

```
Touch /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundSample-bvsqlgnuhfmtjkgkhevztdzbjbie/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Trainer/BuildProductsPath/Release/Trainer.app.dSYM
cd /Users/pbholmen/Projects/SoundSample
/usr/bin/touch -c /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundSample-bvsqlgnuhfmtjkgkhevztdzbjbie/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Trainer/BuildProductsPath/Release/Trainer.app.dSYM

RegisterWithLaunchServices /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundSample-bvsqlgnuhfmtjkgkhevztdzbjbie/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Trainer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Trainer.app
cd /Users/pbholmen/Projects/SoundSample
builtin-lsRegisterURL /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundSample-bvsqlgnuhfmtjkgkhevztdzbjbie/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Trainer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Trainer.app

** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **
```

I have tried to simply copy the Trainer.app that it builds into the /Applications folder, but if I double-click on it, it just won't run. Of course, the Application works when built and run from within XCode, both with the "Debug" and "Release" configuration.

Back when it did work, this would be the last lines of the build log (in Terminal):

```
Touch build/Release/Trainer.app.dSYM
cd /Users/pbholmen/Projects/SoundSample
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/pbholmen/Projects/SoundSample/build/Release/SoundSample.app.dSYM

RegisterWithLaunchServices /Applications/Trainer.app
cd /Users/pbholmen/Projects/SoundSample
builtin-lsRegisterURL /Applications/Trainer.app

** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **
```

If I try to go into the build log from within XCode, find where it puts the builds, and maneuver into that location in Finder and start the application from outside of XCode, that doesn't work either.

Here you can see my Deployment build settings for the target:

[Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eepHp.png)

Under "Deployment location" I have tried both "YES" and "NO", and under "OS X Deployment target" I have tried both "OS X 10.10" and "OS X 10.11". And all four combinations of the two.

Comment: What about using `archive` and installing it from there?

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried it, and it didn't use to work, but works now, after I have set the deployment location of a framework that my target depends on, which is in a different project.

So, I can now install it, but I wish there was a way to do it via the command line (which is quicker), so I'll keep my question open.

Comment: If you want to manage Xcode project dependencies then it sounds like you need to create an Xcode workspace and build that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had already added the external project to my main project, which should also work. I have now figured out the problem, and will write a post to inform other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of twiddling, I finally figured out the answer. First off, the command

```
sudo xcodebuild -scheme Trainer install
```

is wrong. It was a workaround, because I couldn't get XCode to manage my external dependencies from the command line, even though they were managed correctly within XCode. The correct invocation, for a target other than the project's main target is

```
sudo xcodebuild -target Trainer install
```

Previously, the first invocation would work, the product would be installed even though the scheme doesn't really include an "Install" action. This is clearly no longer so with XCode 7.1. The reason I couldn't use `-target` instead of `-scheme` previously, was because my target was dependent on a framework in another project, which was added to my main project (the external *project* was added, not just the framework). All dependencies were set up correctly in my main project, and from the command line it worked only when specifying the scheme, not when specifying the target. When running xcodebuild with `-target` specified, xcodebuild would not find the modules in the external project (a Swift framework).

I have now figured out the reason for this. The project which contained the external framework was not set up correctly. It was set up to install the framework into a bogus location (/tmp/ProjectName.dst/Library/Frameworks, which is the default). In addition, my main project needed to add /Library/Frameworks into the framework search paths. It seems that when the project is built inside XCode, or for archiving etc... libraries and executables are built into a "private" folder structure separate from the system itself. When running xcodebuild install, however, it tries to install the external frameworks into the proper system folders, and link it there. Therefore, setups that work inside XCode may not work when running 'xcodebuild'.

EDIT: It works now, but StackOverflow won't let me mark it as correct before two days.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour is still the same between a scheme and a target in Xcode 8.2.1, even if you have set "Installation Build Product Location" to `/`.